# Smooch - message delivery failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, zendesk, smooch

I have successfully integrated Smooch (Sunshine Conversations) iOS SDK with version 9.0.0 but it randomly not working for some of the users.

Few users reported that their message not sent and provides the following error message and tapping on the following message also does nothing.

```
Message not delivered. Tap to retry.
```

Does anyone face this issue? I read the complete SDK document but there is no way to get an idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually displayed when users are having connectivity issues - tapping on the prompt once the connection has stabilised will retry sending the message to the platform.

Use the widget in your dashboard or email support for further assistance.